# Раздельная компиляция на Visual C++ 2010 Express

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Уважаемые Господа!
Я новичок. Учусь по книге С.Прата "С++ Лекции и упражнения."
При попытке собрать программу из 3 файлов в Visual C++ Express компоновщик выдаёт ошибку
LNK 2019. Неразрешённый внешний символ.
На одном из форумов прочитал, что требуется установить флажок "Создать файл связей".
Путь примерно такой:
Построение  -  параметры  -  компоновщик  -  изменение категории  -  общие  -
 -  установить флажок: "Создать файл связей".
 Не могу найти, где находится компоновщик.
 Может быть в данной среде это вообще невозможно?
Буду очень признателен, если поможете.
С уважением, Андрей.

Прошу прощение, что забыл, - это по первости, - добавить код.
Испралвяюсь.
И ещё. Я работаю в англоязычной версии Visual C++ Express.

```
A_Plus_f_1.cpp // Это название 1-го файла.
-------------------------------------------

#include<iostream>
#include"ashownz.h"

using namespace std ;

int main()
{
    cout << "\n\n\n" << endl ;

    func_show_nz() ;

    cout << "\n\n\n" << endl ;
return (0) ;
}

A_Plus_body_f_2.cpp // Это название 2-го файла.
------------------------------------------------

#include<iostream>
#include"ashownz.h"

    void func_show_nz(  void ) 
    {
        using namespace std ;

        cout <<  "BBB"  << endl  ;
    }

ashownz.h // Это название заголовочного файла.
----------------------------

#ifndef A_SHOW_NZ_H_
#define A_SHOW_NZ_H_

    void func_show_nz( void ) ;

#endif
```

Все ТРИ файла находятся в одной папке, которая лежит на рабочем столе.
Я запускаю Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express, и добавляю ТОЛЬКО 1-й файл.
Этот файл прекрасно компилируется, из чего можно сделать заключение,
что все ТРИ файла компилятору видны.
А вот собрать их все вместе компоновщик не может.

Вот что печатает компоновщик :

------ Build started: Project: eXPerimentCpp, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
A_Plus_f_1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl func_show_nz(void)" (?func_show_nz@@YAXXZ) referenced in function _main
C:\Documents and Settings\Бит\мои документы\visual studio 2010\Projects\eXPerimentCpp\Debug\eXPerimentCpp.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: А можно полный лог ошибки и строку кода, на которой она происходит?

Comment: Уважаемые Господа!
Если можно, ещё одно уточнение.
Почему в обычном исполняемом файле для доступа к необходимым функциям достаточно "включить" только соответствующие заголовочные файлы, в то время как при раздельной компиляции в папку "Sourse File" необходимо включать и файл поддержки, содержащий тела функций.
Это связано только с местоположением стандартных заголовочных файлов, или с чем-то ещё?
С уважением, Андрей.

Comment: @NZMEY: Насколько я знаю, в C++ раздельня компиляция происходит **всегда**. У вас всегда тела функций должны быть скомпилированы. Находятся ли они в виртуальной папке "Source File" или где-то ещё, не играет никакой роли.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> добавляю ТОЛЬКО 1-й файл

Собственно, в этом и проблема. Утверждение

> Этот файл прекрасно компилируется, из чего можно сделать заключение, что все ТРИ файла компилятору видны.

неверно. Компилятор видит **два** файла: `A_Plus_f_1.cpp` (потому что вы его добавили в проект) и `ashownz.h` (потому что строкой `#include"ashownz.h"` вы явным образом указываете, что этот файл лежит в текущей папке). О файле `A_Plus_body_f_2.cpp` компилятор ничего не знает.

Компилятор (простите за тавтологию) компилирует cpp-файлы по отдельности. При этом он "вдит" функции, объявленные в текущем файле, а также сигнатуры функций, объявленные в заголовочных файлах, подключённых к данному cpp-файлу. После компиляции вы получаете объектный файл, в котором вызовы функций представляются именами функций. Затем в дело вступает компоновщик, который для каждой вызываемой функции ищет её реализацию в скомпилированных объектных файлах. Так как компилятор скомпилировал только `A_Plus_f_1.cpp`, реализацию функции `func_show_nz` он нигде найти не может, отсюда и ошибка. Так что добавляйте второй cpp-файл в проект, и будет вам счастье.